# Outlook compile error - procedure declaration does not match

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to auto-forward my Outlook email to another email address using VB code and I keep getting a compile error.

The error I get when I compile the code is "procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name".

```
Sub Application_NewMail(myMailToFW As Outlook.MailItem)

    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myemails = myInbox.Items
    Set mynewemails = myemails.Restrict("[unread]=true")

    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To myemails.Count Step 1
    If myemails(x).UnRead(True) Then
    Dim myMailToFW As Outlook.MailItem
Set myMailToFW = myemails(x)
Set myMailToFW = myMailToFW.forward
myMailToFW.Recipients.Add ("email@email.com")
myMailToFW.Send
myemails(x).UnRead = False
End If
Next

End Sub
```

I changed email@email.com to the email i want to forward to.

Comment: [`NewMail`'s handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmail) doesn't take parameters.

Comment: So I should just change "NewMail" to "ItemAdd"?

Comment: It all depends on the event you're trying to use to run your code, and that depends on your objective for what you want the code to do and under what circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Your [class module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#class-module) has a procedure name that conflicts with the name of an event.

A [procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#procedure) has the same name as an event, but does not have the same signature (that is, the number and types of the [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#parameter)). This can occur if you do something such as add a new parameter to an event procedure.

If the procedure isn't the event procedure corresponding to the event, change its name. If the procedure corresponds to the event, make the parameter list agree with that required by the event (if any).

For more information, you could refer to this link:

[Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having same name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/procedure-declaration-does-not-match-description-of-event-or-procedure-having-sa)